# Cannot find module 'babel-loader' Require stack:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Hope you are all doing well? I'm running this react app and then I ran npm eject to eject the app so I can add the web packs features. Now when I run npm or yarn start, it doesn't work. It then pulls the error as follows.

```
Cannot find module 'babel-loader'
Require stack:
```

I still don't know what the error is because I did not touch any babel-loader in the webpack.config file.
Anyone know what the error is and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably, you don't have this package in `node_modules`. Try to run `yarn` or `npm i` to install all the missing packages. If it didn't help, please, include stack trace of the error, there is might be useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `eject`, React APP development dependencies declarations (from internal `package.json` files) and relative configuration files are hoisted to the root of your project. However, previously installed dependencies are left behind.

Deleting your `node_modules` directory and running `yarn install` again will most likely fix the problem.